# How to stream video from Pi running Bullseye in HTML? (Pre-Bullseye do not work anymore)

Tags: camera, streaming-video, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, libcamera

I'm trying to stream video from my Pi running Bullseye 32 bit (with camera OV5647) available on HTML on another device over LAN. I do not want to use the legacy stack as it causes problems with VNC to the Pi.

(i) Pre-Bullseye method does not work since raspivid amd raspistill are no longer avaialable on Bullseye. Existing repos like Motion and picamera no longer work on Bullseye. Previous solutions which worked with Buster and earlier (pre November 2021) no longer work.
(ii) I've executed "**libcamera-vid -t 0 --width 1080 --height 720 -q 100 -n --codec mjpeg --inline --listen -o tcp://192.168.0.75:8888 -v**" and then the stream is available on VLC on a Windows device on the LAN when opened with "**tcp/mjpeg://192.168.0.75:8888**"
(iii) I want the stream to be viewed at https://: preferably with time and datestamps and this perhaps need the Pi to act like a video server providing video on DEMAND.